# Windows Phone 8.1 Development: How to Bind Data from the Deserialized Json Root Object for the List View

Tags: json, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I am learning WP 8.1 app development, and now doing one simple weather app: I am reading the weather Json data from http://openweathermap.org/, the Json data itself is successfully retrieved, but I have problem to bind the data to my List View. Here is the detail:

```
{
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0907,
"city": {
    "id": 658225,
    "name": "Helsinki",
    "coord": {
        "lon": 24.93545,
        "lat": 60.169521
    },
    "country": "FI",
    "population": 558457
},
"cnt": 7,
"list": [
    {
        "dt": 1426413600,
        "temp": {
            "day": 272.64,
            "min": 270.84,
            "max": 272.64,
            "night": 270.84,
            "eve": 272.64,
            "morn": 272.64
        },
        "pressure": 1062.73,
        "humidity": 89,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "sky is clear",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "speed": 5.01,
        "deg": 70,
        "clouds": 0
    },
    {
        "dt": 1426500000,
        "temp": {
            "day": 274.26,
            "min": 271.16,
            "max": 274.26,
            "night": 272.43,
            "eve": 273.39,
            "morn": 271.16
        },
        "pressure": 1065.67,
        "humidity": 90,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "sky is clear",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "speed": 2.76,
        "deg": 78,
        "clouds": 0
    },
    {
        "dt": 1426586400,
        "temp": {
            "day": 274.51,
            "min": 272.16,
            "max": 274.7,
            "night": 272.99,
            "eve": 273.9,
            "morn": 272.16
        },
        "pressure": 1062,
        "humidity": 92,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "sky is clear",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "speed": 3.66,
        "deg": 170,
        "clouds": 0
    },
    {
        "dt": 1426672800,
        "temp": {
            "day": 274.69,
            "min": 272.04,
            "max": 275.19,
            "night": 272.18,
            "eve": 274.77,
            "morn": 272.04
        },
        "pressure": 1056.08,
        "humidity": 94,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "sky is clear",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "speed": 2.02,
        "deg": 225,
        "clouds": 0
    },
    {
        "dt": 1426759200,
        "temp": {
            "day": 277.33,
            "min": 275.68,
            "max": 277.33,
            "night": 275.68,
            "eve": 276.02,
            "morn": 275.87
        },
        "pressure": 1016.04,
        "humidity": 0,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10d"
            }
        ],
        "speed": 4.95,
        "deg": 256,
        "clouds": 81,
        "rain": 0.47
    },
    {
        "dt": 1426845600,
        "temp": {
            "day": 275.47,
            "min": 271.06,
            "max": 275.47,
            "night": 271.06,
            "eve": 273.94,
            "morn": 275.27
        },
        "pressure": 1027.17,
        "humidity": 0,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 600,
                "main": "Snow",
                "description": "light snow",
                "icon": "13d"
            }
        ],
        "speed": 4.8,
        "deg": 30,
        "clouds": 92,
        "snow": 0.04
    },
    {
        "dt": 1426932000,
        "temp": {
            "day": 274.33,
            "min": 270.47,
            "max": 274.33,
            "night": 270.47,
            "eve": 272.02,
            "morn": 270.9
        },
        "pressure": 1035.35,
        "humidity": 0,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "sky is clear",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "speed": 2.81,
        "deg": 84,
        "clouds": 3
    }
]
}
```

Then weather data class is generated and referred to http://json2csharp.com/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WeatherApp.Models
{

    public class WeatherData
    {

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string cod { get; set; }
        public double message { get; set; }
        public City city { get; set; }
        public int cnt { get; set; }

        public List<Day> list { get; set; }
    }


    public class Coord
    {
        public double lon { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
    }


    public class City
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public int population { get; set; }
    }


    public class Temp
    {
        public double day { get; set; }
        public double min { get; set; }
        public double max { get; set; }
        public double night { get; set; }
        public double eve { get; set; }
        public double morn { get; set; }
    }


    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }


    public class Day
    {
        //public int dt { get; set; }
        private int _dt;
        public int dt
        {
            get { return _dt; }
            set
            {
                _dt = value;
                var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                time = epoch.AddSeconds(value);
            }
        }

        private DateTime _time;
        public DateTime time
        {
            get { return _time; }
            set { _time = value; }
        }

        public Temp temp { get; set; }
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public int deg { get; set; }
        public int clouds { get; set; }
        public double? rain { get; set; }
        public double? snow { get; set; }
    }
    }
}
```

From WeatherInforPage.xaml.cs:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        String receiveText = e.Parameter.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("WeatherInfoPage received handed over weather information: " + receiveText);

        Models.WeatherData.RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.WeatherData.RootObject>(receiveText);
        cityName.Text = result.city.name;
        cityInfo.Text = "Population: " + result.city.population;

        listWeather.ItemsSource = result.list;
    }
```

The Json data is passed from another page, and the Root Object is deserialized correctly.
I add one break point to check it:

[image]

But I can't get the corresponding test block binding data.

The key part in my WeatherInfoPage.xaml is:

```
        <Pivot Title="">
        <PivotItem Header="Weather">
            <ListView Name="listWeather">
                <ListView.Header >
                    <StackPanel Height="84">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="cityName" FontSize="35" Height="45"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="cityInfo" FontSize="25" Foreground="Orange" Height="40"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListView.Header>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Width="360" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF2996AE">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding time}" FontSize="25"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding main}" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Stretch="Uniform"
                                    Width="60" Height="60"/>
                                    <Image Stretch="Uniform"
                                   Width="60" Height="60"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding day}" FontSize="25"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding night}" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

After I run this app in my emulator, I got error from the debug:

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'main' property not found on 'WeatherApp.Models.WeatherData+Day, WeatherApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='main' DataItem='WeatherApp.Models.WeatherData+Day, WeatherApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'day' property not found on 'WeatherApp.Models.WeatherData+Day, WeatherApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='day' DataItem='WeatherApp.Models.WeatherData+Day, WeatherApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'night' property not found on 'WeatherApp.Models.WeatherData+Day, WeatherApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='night' DataItem='WeatherApp.Models.WeatherData+Day, WeatherApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

And the corresponding data is not shown in my List View too. 
Please help me, how to bind those data from Root Object? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your data by going one more level down in the object.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding main}" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
```

above should be replaced by

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding weather[0].main}" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
```

It is not exact solution that you should **copy-paste** but it's a hint and shows that your UI design is not reflecting the data you trying to bind. weather is a list/collection so it should be shown in listview not in textbox.

**Trying to explain it :-**
If you see carefully then you will find that `time` property is getting binded successfully But not your main property. It is because `main` property is not as at a same level of `time` property that's what you exception is telling you clearly. 
So before binding to any nested property first try to find at which level the property available then just navigate using `.` part level is more than 1.

Comment: I tried again with explicit path about the binding data, seems it still doesn't work: for instance, the "main" property is under Weather.main, and I modify the line as: <TextBlock Text="{Binding weather.main}" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>

Comment: @RuiHuang Try weather[0].main inplace of weather.main then think why weather[0] ..

Comment: weather here is a list, and if we set weather[0].main, it will fill up all list items with the same content. So, is there any way to do the data binding grammatically?